# How to prevent submitting search form when search field is empty?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here the code below disables search button when search box is empty. When input type for search button is set to `submit` then neither submit nor the enter key from keyboard submits empty form but when I change input type to `button` and put the cursor inside input field and press enter button even empty form is posted causing reloading of page. How to prevent submitting search form on pressing enter when search field is empty?

```
<form action="search.php" method="post">
<input type="text" class="search" placeholder="search here"/>
<input type="submit" class="Button" value="search"/>
</form> 

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('.Button').attr('disabled',true);
$('.search').keyup(function(){
if($(this).val().length !=0)
    $('.Button').attr('disabled', false);            
else
    $('.Button').attr('disabled',true);
 })
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is your code with some modification:

[**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamuttamkumarroy/19tuLu0m/embedded/result/)

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 // By default submit is disabled 
 $('.Button').prop('disabled', true);

 $('.search').keyup(function() {

  if($(this).val().length !=0 ) {   
   $('.Button').prop('disabled', false); 
  } else {
   $( ".search").focus();  
      $('.Button').prop('disabled', true);
      e.preventDefault();
  }
  
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="search.php" method="post">
 <input type="text" class="search" placeholder="search here"/>
 <input type="submit" class="Button" value="search"/>
</form>
```

[**JsFiddle Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/iamuttamkumarroy/19tuLu0m/embedded/result/)

Answer (score 3):

Add a event listener for the form submission

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    // check logic here
    if ($('.search').val().length < 1)
       e.preventDefault()
});
```

where `e.preventDefault` will avoid the form being submitted if no value

otherwise the form will submitted normally

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this

```
$('form').submit(function(e){
    if ($('.search').val().length<=0)
        return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you should use [prop](http://api.jquery.com/prop/) instead of `attr` if you want to change `disabled`

```
$(function() {
  $('.Button').prop('disabled', true);
  $('.search').keyup(function() {
    $('.Button').prop('disabled', !$(this).val());
  });
});
```